# How to write a generic function template for openssl bignum?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, bignum

I m looking to create a simple general function template for the openssl
bignum library. I want it to have all the biolerplate includes and other stuff already present and it should follow the same pattern as the other bignum functions. It should like something like:

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>    

int Big_Func(BIGNUM* RESULT, BIGNUM *X, BIGNUM *Y){
     //biolerplate bignum stuff

    //your code goes here

   // more biolerplate
}
```

I m leaving an answer i found based on bn_gcd but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
include <openssl/bn.h>
include <stdio.h>
```

/*
This function supposes its being called inside another function, like
main, which has its bn_ctx vars to pass to the func
 */

```
int BN_func(BIGNUM *R, BIGNUM *in_a,BIGNUM *in_b, BN_CTX *ctx)
{
 BIGNUM *a, *b, *t;//declare ptrs of type BIGNUM
 int ret = 0;//return code

bn_check_top(in_a);//checktop does makes sure the
                 // internal array is nonempty
bn_check_top(in_b);

BN_CTX_start(ctx);//BigNum context usedto obtain temp BN vars from
// a BN_CTX which have already been created by using BN_CTX_new
a = BN_CTX_get(ctx);//gets ptr from ctx
b = BN_CTX_get(ctx);//
if (a == NULL || b == NULL) //checks if ptr is NULL; 
                    //if so, exits immediately.
    goto err;

if (BN_copy(a, in_a) == NULL)//copy the func params to local ctx vars
  goto err;        //check if null as above
if (BN_copy(b, in_b) == NULL)
 goto err;
a->neg = 0;// sets neg to 0 indicating positive qty.
b->neg = 0;
/*after all that we can calculate with the 'a' and 'b' params safely*/

//your code here

   /*on error go here*/
 err:
   BN_CTX_end(ctx);
   bn_check_top(R);
   return (ret);
}
```